# Did Estarossa Full Counter against Escanor didnt work or Escanor was faster than him?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the battle of Escanor vs Estarossa, at the end, Estarossa charges against Escanor and he said to have reflected his attack with Full Counter but after some seconds he finds he was cut but Escanor. What does this mean? Did Estarossa Full Counter against Escanor didnt work because Escanor attack was too powerful, or Escanor was faster than him?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah he full countered Escanor which is why Escanor got some injuries but after sometime Escanor seems to become faster that even Estarossa can't see his attack since Escanor grows stronger and faster every seconds.